# Send arbitrary message youtube using c#

Tags: youtube-api

I'm trying to send an arbitrary message using C# to a YouTube user.  I've learned you can only  send messages to contacts if using the YouTube API within C#.  Trying to see if anyone knows of anyway of sending to an arbitrary user, similar to "TubeToolbox", very popular program.

Answer (score 0):

That's not supported at all via the YouTube API.

Comment: Yes, this is true.  But how is the TubeToolbox program sending messages to arbitrary people.  Check out the program (google search).  Use it and you'll see what I'm talking about.  There should be other options.  Any suggestions?

Comment: That's a question for the author of the program. And I'd strongly recommend that whatever the answer to that question is, you only take actions that are allowed by the YouTube Terms of Service.

Comment: Well if you read the Q&A on Tubetoolboxes website, they are not going against YouTube Terms.  You're not exactly spamming, but sending messages at different intervals.  Somewhat at the speed of what a human would do sitting behind the computer.  The program would just be emulating the actions for you.